# Expected linking error in C++ but executable builds fine

Tags: c++

I have pasted the code below. I was expecting lines `Circle {p, radius}` and `Circle::draw()` to cause linking error because Circle constructor as well as the `draw` functions are merely declarations without definitions. However, the executable gets created properly without any linking errors. Why is there no linking error here?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Point {
    public:
        double x() {
            return x_coordinate;
        }
        double y() {
            return y_coordinate;
        }
    private:
        double x_coordinate, y_coordinate;
};

class Shape {
    public:
        virtual Point center() const =0;
        virtual void move(Point to) =0;
        virtual void draw() const =0;
        virtual void rotate(int angle) =0;
        virtual ~Shape() {}
};

class Circle: public Shape {
    public:
        Circle(Point p, int radius);
        Point center() {
            return c;
        }
        void move(Point to) {
            c = to;
        }
        void draw() const override; 
        void rotate(int angle) override {}
    private:
        Point c;    
        int r;
};

class Smiley: public Circle {
    public:
        Smiley(Point p, int radius):
            Circle {p, radius}, mouth {nullptr} {}

        ~Smiley() {
            delete mouth;
            for(auto eye: eyes) {
                delete eye;
            }
        }

        void move(Point to) override;
        void draw() const override {
            Circle::draw();
            for(auto e: eyes) {
                e->draw();
            }
            mouth->draw();
        }
        void rotate(int angle) override;
        void add_eye(Shape *eye) {
            eyes.push_back(eye);
        }
        void set_mouth(Shape *s);
        virtual void wink(int i);
    private:
        vector<Shape *>eyes;
        Shape *mouth;
};

void rotate_all(vector<Shape*>& v, int angle) {
    for(auto p : v) {
        p->rotate(angle);
    }
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but you failed to initialize the members `x_coordinate` and `y_coordinate` of the `Point` class.  Thus a program as simple as this: `int main() { Point p; Point p1; p = p1; }` invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no linker errors because:

```cpp
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Your program does not need to link to any method other than main to work, and main doesn't do anything.

Comment: So even though the compiler is aware of potential linking problems it will go ahead and build the executable because the classes are not being used?

Comment: @sshekhar1980 -- Yes.  If the function is never called, the linker doesn't consider that function.  Also the job of the compiler is not to figure out if the function actually exists.  That is the job of the linker, and again, only if the function is actually being called by the program.  If the linker didn't do this, your final program may be gigabytes in size, given all of the `#include`'s that may be used.

Comment: Correct. If you just add some extern void missinFunc() declaration prior to an empty main, it will still build the exe. If however you added __declspec(dllexport) infront of that prototype, then it will fail to build.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor `Circle(Point, int)` is never called **except from inline functions.** Since those inline functions are never called, the code for them is not emitted, and you get no link error.

If you call one of these functions from a **non-inline** function, you will get an error (with a typical toolchain--this may depend on whether you do things like enable LTO). For example, make this change:

Redeclare the `Smiley` constructor as non-inline:

```
Smiley(Point p, int radius);
```

Provide a definition outside the class (remember that member functions **defined** inside the class body are inline by default):

```
Smiley::Smiley(Point p, int radius):
    Circle {p, radius}, mouth {nullptr} {}
```

You will now get a link error. This is the error I get:

```
$ c++ test.cpp 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw9y6G0.o: warning: relocation against `_ZTV6Smiley' in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw9y6G0.o: in function `Smiley::Smiley(Point, int)':
test.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `Circle::Circle(Point, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: test.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `vtable for Smiley'
/usr/bin/ld: warning: creating DT_TEXTREL in a PIE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Exit: 1]
```

Comment: Slightly incorrect reasoning I'm afraid. inline has nothing to do with it. By default your compiler is set to DSO export the vtable & non-inline funcs from the executable. Add -fvisibility=hidden to your command line args, and it will link just fine. Hidden symbols is the default on Windows, so this will compile just fine in VC++.

Comment: @robthebloke: With `-fvisibility=hidden` I get the same error. Can you provide steps to reproduce?